# Updating a Image field in SQL server

Tags: c#

I am trying to update mu existing image field in one of my table and I am getting error saying "A generic error occurred in GDI+". Please  help.

```
private void Add_Records()
    {
        int i = check_for_null();
        if (i == 1)
        {
            DateTime Nw = DateTime.Now;
            int user = Form_Common_Login.user_id;
            int ref_lc = 0;
            ref_lc = Convert.ToInt16(cbo_emp_cat.SelectedValue);

            try
            {
                string query = @"INSERT INTO tbl_Labour_Employee_Reg
                (Ref_IDLC,First_Name,Last_Name,Emp_Image,Designation,NIC_No,Emp_Address,Previous_WorkPlaces,Phone_Number_Mobile,Phone_Number_Residential,Account_Number,Employee_Number,Remarks,Accessed_By,Accessed_Time,Is_Deleted,Is_Active)
                VALUES ('" + ref_lc + "','" + txt_Fname.Text + "','" + txt_Lname.Text + "',@image_array,'" + txt_designation.Text + "','" + txt_nic.Text + "','" + txt_address.Text + "','" + txt_previous_wp.Text + "','" + txt_Mnumber.Text + "','" + txt_Lnumber.Text + "','" + txt_account_number.Text + "','" + txt_emp_number.Text + "','" + txt_remarks.Text + "','" + user + "','" + Nw + "',0,1)";
                clz_Common_SqlConnection con = new clz_Common_SqlConnection();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query ,con.ActiveCon ());
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ();
                pic_box_employee.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] image_array = ms.ToArray();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_array", image_array);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        else { MessageBox.Show("Please enter Valid Data"); }
    }
```

my update code here

```
private void Update_Records()
    {
        int i = check_for_null();
        if (i == 1)
        {
            DateTime Nw = DateTime.Now;
            int user = Form_Common_Login.user_id;
            int ref_lc = 0;
            ref_lc = Convert.ToInt16(cbo_emp_cat.SelectedValue);

            try
            {
                string update_query = "UPDATE tbl_Labour_Employee_Reg"+
                "SET Ref_IDLC ='"+ref_lc+"',First_Name = ,'" + txt_Fname.Text + "',Last_Name='" + txt_Lname.Text + "',Emp_Image = @image_array,Designation = '" + txt_designation.Text + "',NIC_No='" + txt_nic.Text + "',Emp_Address = '" + txt_address.Text + "'"+
                ",Previous_WorkPlaces = '" + txt_previous_wp.Text + "', Phone_Number_Mobile = '" + txt_Mnumber.Text + "',Phone_Number_Residential='" + txt_Lnumber.Text + "', Account_Number= '" + txt_account_number.Text + "',Employee_Number='" + txt_emp_number.Text + "'"+
                ",Remarks='" + txt_remarks.Text + "',Accessed_By='" + user + "',Accessed_Time= '" + Nw + "',Is_Deleted=0,Is_Active=1";

                clz_Common_SqlConnection con = new clz_Common_SqlConnection();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update_query, con.ActiveCon());
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                pic_box_employee.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] image_array = ms.ToArray();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_array", image_array);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }                
        }

        else { MessageBox.Show("Please enter Valid Data"); } 
   }
```

Insert function is properly working but the update is not. I am really struck in here. If you have better way to insert & update a image field please explain.

Comment: Why why why do you glue that query together and pass everything as text when you apparently know how to use SQL Parameters?  You also didnt say where you get the error

Comment: I am getting a error in following line of code which is under "Update Records"                                                                         pic_box_employee.Image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Answer (score 0):

First of all move your answer to your question. Its not an answer. Its just a new question.

try using the following, I personally update images as follows;

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Awais\Desktop\image.png");
byte[] arr;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    arr = ms.ToArray();
}
int dr = 0;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; initial catalog=database; uid=sa;pwd=password;");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update table set I1 = @img", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", arr);
con.Open();
using (con)
{
    dr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: your method is just as mine..Could you please highlight where I have done wrong coding....

Comment: using block for memorystream